# MATLAB: solving 1st order hyperbolic equation in 2 spacial dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection#Mathematics_of_advection), the equation

$$\psi_t + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \psi =0$$

is hyperbolic. However, when I want to solve it in MATLAB using the pde toolbox ([link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/product-description.html)), the general formula for a hyperbolic equation appears to be:

$$\psi_{tt} - \nabla \cdot (C\nabla\psi)+a\psi=f$$

Which is hyperbolic yes, but second order. I can't seem to find a way how to solve a simpler, 1st order problem. Maybe there is some way to transform it? I can't find anything in the toolbox documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to use the toolbox ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/327503)), but it should be simple to implement a [finite difference method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method) by hand:

Write

$$
\psi_t = -u_1 \psi_x - u_2 \psi_y,
$$

then discretize (I'll use the first-order forward difference in $t$, and the first-order centered difference in $x,y$)

$$
\frac{\psi(t + h) - \psi(t)}{h}\\
 = -u_1(x,y)\frac{\frac12\psi(x+k,y) - \frac12\psi(x-k,y)}{k} -u_2(x,y)\frac{\frac12\psi(x,y+k) - \frac12\psi(x,y-k)}{k}
$$
so
$$
\psi(t + h) = \\
 \psi(t) -\frac{h}{2k}\left(u_1(x,y)(\psi(x+k,y) - \psi(x-k,y)) +u_2(x,y)(\psi(x,y+k) - \psi(x,y-k))\right).
$$

Then your method is something like (assuming you are solving on $(t,x,y) \in [0,T] \times [0,L_x] \times [0,L_y]$)

```
psi(0,x,y) = initial_condition(x,y);
for t = 0 : h : T
    for x = 0 : k : L_x
        for y = 0 : k : L_y
            psi(t + h,x,y) = psi(t,x,y) ...
             - (h/(2*k))*(u_1(x,y)*(psi(t,x+k,y) - psi(t,x-k,y)) ...
             + u_2(x,y)*(psi(t,x,y+k) - psi(t,x,y-k)));
        end
    end
end
```

In practice, you will want `psi` to have integer indices, but this illustrates the main idea; you will also need to treat the boundary more carefully, notice `phi(t,x,y-k)` is going to give you problems for $y = 0$, etc. There is also some need to consider whether this scheme converges, etc. (this can depend on the choice of discretization, as well as the relative size of $h$ and $k$).

For more on all this, I recommend looking at Strikwerda's book. I know this probably seems like a lot to go through and learn just to solve a single PDE, but I can promise you this is a very useful general skillset to have if you think there are more PDEs in your future (in which case, you will quickly outgrow the Matlab toolbox).

Comment: In practice in MATLAB, you probably want to eschew the two inner loops over x and y in favor of fast difference operations like "diff" or "gradient". I implemented this idea with "gradient" with good results. With integer indicies, it looks something like [PSIX, PSIY] = gradient(psi(:,:,tt)); psi(:,:,tt + 1) = psi(:,:,tt) - (h/(2*k))*(u_1.*(PSIX) + u_2.*(PSIY));

Comment: Indeed. I usually vectorize $\psi$ and make the spatial derivative operator a matrix, so that there's only one loop (in $t$), and the update is just `phi{n + 1} = A*phi{n}`. But this requires using `kron` and tends to obfuscate what is actually happening. The loops are slow, but lay bare the details.

Comment: @BaronVT I found Strikwerda's book, but I'm not sure which section is relevant reading. Where would I look to find an improvement to the scheme I'm using atm?

Comment: I would recommend reading at least the first chapter. I have sort of written a crash course of the first half of that chapter, but reading a more detailed exposition will surely help you understand what you're doing (rather than just taking my word for it).